# Laravel 5.5 Spatie Permission doesn't create role

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I'm using laravel 5.5 and spatie / laravel-permission ":" ^ 2.38 ". I created a simple controller for creating a role, but laravel returns the error:

> Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException
>   "name"
>   My simple controller is:

```
<?php

namespace App;
namespace App\Http\Controllers\UserRole;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Role;
use App\Permission;
use DB;

class RolePermission extends Controller
{
public function create_role(){

    Role::create(['name' => 'noc']);

}
}
```

Comment: The controller is just a test to testing spatie/laravel-permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to Spatie. You must allow the Role object to be mass-assignable. In your case, you must put:

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

to your Role model, or:

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

See more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Okay it seems to work. Now it gives me this error: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'guard_name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `roles` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (noc, 2020-05-27 14:09:56, 2020-05-27 14:09:56))

Comment: What did you add to the Role class?

Comment: protected $fillable = ['name'];

Comment: You've created your own model. You shouldn't. You must directly use Spatie's Role object. That is why is the error. Instead of App\Role, you must use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role.

Comment: You've marked the question as answererd. I'd like to ask you to click the "up" arrow above the "0". Thanks!